# Инжект в процесс dwm.exe

Tags: c++, windows, dwm

Я бы хотел реализовать один быстрый способ получения скриншотов. Неоднократно встречал упоминания такого метода. Заключается он во внедрении в процесс dwm.exe собственного кода с целью получения информации о событиях перерисовки окон, т.е. об изменении областей экрана и получении содержимого этих областей.

Владеет кто более подробной информацией о том, как это делается? Мне нужно установить хук на вызов какого-то метода перерисовки? У dwm.exe должно быть есть какая-то защита от инжекта? Как её обойти?

**UPD:** Исходим из того, что мы уже выполняем свой код в процессе dwm.exe. Что делать, чтобы получить нужную информацию?

**UPD2:** Может быть кто-то знает какие конкретно функции вызывает процесс dwm.exe при "рисовании"? Можно было бы тогда на них хук поставить.

Comment: Защита от инжекта на уровне ОС: нет прав - нет инжекта. Установленный АВ тоже не порадуется такому поведению.

Comment: Ну конечно я подразумеваю наличие прав админа и привилегий отладчика. Давайте так же предположим, что антивируса тоже нет. Идеальная ситуация (эти трудности я буду решать позже, этой темы они не касаются).

Comment: Как бы вопрос не конкретно об инжекте. Вернее, он о том, что делать для решения задачи при установке, что наша dll **уже инжектирована** в процесс. Какие инструкции надо исполнять в "захваченном" процессе dwm, чтобы понять когда происходит перерисовка (обновление) областей экрана и как извлечь эти области?

Comment: Конечно, у меня могут и возникнуть проблемы конкретно с самим внедрением. Не спорю. Но если этот вопрос таки возникнет, я задам его отдельно.